# 2008-2009 года рождения или годов рождения?

Tags: согласование, числительные, единственное-множественное-число, цифры, наращение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: учащиеся 1 и 2 класса или классов, учащиеся 3-7 классов или класс, лыжники 2008-2009 года рождения или годов рождения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Учащиеся 1-го и 2-го классов, 3—7-го классов**, хотя интервал с наращением — не очень хороший вариант, лучше писать словами.

По поводу числа (ед. или мн.) ответ находим у Розенталя:

> Ср.: старосты восьмого и девятого классов (расчлененное понятие) – он был отличником в восьмом и девятом классе (понятие целого) (§[194. Два определения при одном существительном](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm))

Но Грамота.ру  другого мнения:

> Вопрос № 273152
>   Правильно ли я понимаю, что при указании интервала в порядковых числительных всегда используется тире, а не дефис? То есть нормативным считается написание 
>   "ученики 1—2-х классов"? И неверным будет написание "ученики 1-2-х классов"?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Лучше написать: ученики 1-го и 2-го класса. Если первых и вторых классов несколько, то лучше писать словами: ученики первых и вторых классов.

Исходя из той же логики, по Розенталю должно быть **Лыжники 2008—2009 годов рождения**, но Грамота.ру утверждает иное:

> Вопрос № 261428
>   Как правильно: 1. в именительном падеже 1994-1997 год (годы, года) рождения ???????
>   2. среди юношей 1991-1993 года (годов) рождения ???????
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   1. 1994-1997 год рождения.
>   2. 1991-1993 года рождения.
>
> Вопрос № 253222
>    Ответьте, пожалуйста, как правильно произнести: "...юноши 1993-1994 года (или годов?) рождения"
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Предпочтительно: ...года рождения.

В Нацкорпусе мне удалось найто только один пример с ед. ч.

> Для «средних возрастов» (мужчины 1953-1966 года рождения, женщины 1957-1966 года рождения) на накопление идет 2 процента от суммы годового заработка. [Ирина Невинная. Вот бумажку принесли. Что теперь с ней делать? (2003) // «Российская газета», 2003.09.15]

Примеров с мн. ч. — около 40. Вот один из них.

> Не забудем, что это были мальчики 1921 ― 1922 годов рождения. [И. С. Шкловский. Новеллы и популярные статьи (1982)]

Примечание 1. Номера классов требуют буквенного наращения. Подробности здесь: [Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Примечание 2. Для обозначения интервалов ставится тире. Нужно различать: 
5-7 рисунков (примерное значение) и рисунки 5—7 (интервал).
Как указано у Мильчина (6.1.5. Интервал значений), тире в качестве знака интервала ставится между числами в цифровой форме и по техн. правилам набора не отбивается от цифр.

Comment: *Учащиеся 1-го и 2-го классов* — Грамота даёт [другой ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273152).

Comment: @grizzly, Думаю, правила на этот счет не такие строгие, поэтому Грамота и Розенталь разошлись во мнениях.

Comment: Хорошо бы разобраться. У меня создаётся впечатление, что во всех случаях должно быть множественное число. Либо что-то изменилось в правилах, либо Грамота ошибается в обоих случаях. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в Гуглокнигах (или Нацкорпусе) поиск по "годов рождения". Там очень много приличных изданий ещё с советских времён. PS. У Вас одна из цитат задвоилась.

Comment: @grizzly Если вчитаться, Розенталя тоже не поймешь. Почему  "рабочие первой и второй смены", но "старосты восьмого и девятого классов"?

Comment: Согласен. Про наращения только: «не очень хороший вариант»  здесь — нехорош, т.  к. это не порядковые числительные в полном смысле, а или прилагательное, или существительные.

Comment: @shampar,  У Мильчина находим: 50—60-е годы; в 20—30-х гг. Значит такое допустимо. Чем это отличается от "3—7-го классов"?

Comment: В представлении о школьных классах важна не просто порядковость, а количество и качество, то бишь возраст и уровень знаний. Поэтому, согласен, лучше писать словами.

Comment: @shampar Хочу понять Вашу точку зрения. По-Вашему, "3—7-го рядов" допустимо, а "3—7-го классов" нет?

Comment: В моей точке зрения не было слов допустимо/недопустимо: если числительное строго не порядковое, то наращение при нём необязательно.

Comment: @shampar Что значит "строго не порядковое"?

Comment: Ученик 7 класса перешёл в восьмой: он окончил 7 классов. Налицо количество и качество.

Comment: @shampar Ученик 7 класса — без наращения? Мне кажется, это ошибка. Посмотрел в Нацкорпусе. Так писали **иногда** до революции, но теперь  так не пишут.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что в этих случаях при числительном, где суммарные значения равны двум, пяти и двум, необходимо иметь существительные во мн. числе.